Spring Security Reactive: how to restart authentication in a WebFilter
I configured Spring Security in an application using WebFlux in order to use the OAuth2 Login feature. I'm trying to implement a security filter which verifies the JWT access token and if the access token is expired then the authentication process should restart from scratch, redirecting the user to the identity provider login page.
The problem is that I'm not able to restart the authentication process; I'd like to execute the same steps which occur when (for example) the user's HTTP session expires, in a such case the user is redirected to the Identity Provider login page by Spring Security.
The first approach I tried is throwing an AccessDeniedException as follows:
public class StackOverflowWebFilter implements WebFilter {


private class RestartException extends RuntimeException {
    
}

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {


    
    return restartAuth().doOnSuccess(shouldRestart -> {
        if(shouldRestart) throw new RestartException();
    } )
    .then(chain.filter(exchange))
    .onErrorMap(RestartException.class,t->{
        log.error(t.getMessage(),t);
        return new AccessDeniedException("Restart login requested",t);
    });

}

private Mono<Boolean>  restartAuth(){
    // it takes the decision about restarting authentication process
    ....
}

}

The filter is registered as follows:
http.addFilterAfter(new StackOverflowWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION);

But the the result I get is a blank page containing the exception message:

The second attempt is explicitly handling the redirect process:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class StackOverflowWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    
    private class RestartException extends RuntimeException {
        
    }
    
        
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
                    
        
        return restartAuth().doOnSuccess(shouldRestart -> {
            if(shouldRestart) throw new RestartException();
        } )            
        .then(chain.filter(exchange))
        .onErrorResume(RestartException.class,t -> {
            RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint(
                    "oauth2/authorization/gateway");
            
            return exchange.getSession().flatMap(s->s.invalidate()).then(entryPoint.commence(exchange, null));
            
            
        });

    }
    
    private Mono<Boolean>  restartAuth(){
        // decides if authentication should restart...
        ...
    }

}

The user is redirected to the identity provider login page, but after authentication the user is not redirected to the original requested page; in fact, the url oauth2/authorization/gateway is cached by org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.WebSessionServerRequestCache and the browser is redirected to that url. I know that I could customize the url cache management in some way, but I'd like to know if a cleaner approach exists.

With oauth2Login, applications are OAuth2 clients and request authorization is based on session cookies, not on Bearer tokens (those are used only on oauth2ResourceServer on which you can't "login" because it is stateless by nature).

Also, if your app intends to be restful, it should return 401 to unauthorized requests and it should be what consumes it that decides how to handle this (display an error, use something like a request interceptor to redirect to authorization initiation endpoint, or whatever). I explained how to create an OAuth2 backend for Single-Page Applications in this Baeldung article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2

@ch4mp I don't care about the duration of session cookies, I need to check the validity of the IdP session. For example, suppose that the IdP session is revoked: the user will continue to use the application for all the duration of the cookie session. Adding a check of the access token and trying to refresh it when it's expired allows to force a new login on the IdP.

If you want your client with oauth2Login to be notified with sessions termination on the IDP, then you should activate Back-Channel Logout. With the starter I wrote and use in the article linked above, this a matter of turning on an application property.

@ch4mp does your starter support clustered instances for Back-Channel Logout? My Spring Cloud Gateway uses spring session backed by Redis. If the Oidc session is terminated by KeyCloak, only one instance will be notified and the default spring implementation of OidcSessionRegistry is an in-memory implementation. So, is your starter able to remove the Oidc Session in all the instances of the application? Thanks

With Spring Session, actions on sessions from an instance should be propagated to all instances (that's the point of Spring Session: the session is shared). So, on the OpenID Provider, configure the Back-Channel Logout callback to the Gateway public network interface and the instance processing the request should close the session (destroying all tokens in the shared session). All other gateway instances should be aware of that. Note that "my" starter is not involved here beyond helping to activate Back-Channel Logout on the gateway with a property instead of Java conf.
